# Angular 8 @HostListener('window:scroll', []) not working

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-directive

I have attempted to use HostListener to track the scroll position to change colour of the my header.

My header component is as follows,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    console.log(window.scrollY);
  }

}
```

but when I am scrolling I am not getting any logs in console.

I have trying putting the HostListener in the main app.component, as my header component is positing fixed, However I am still getting no results, and no errors.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure that your `HeaderComponent` has a tall enough height that allows scrolling? (if it doesn't then it will never trigger)

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue right now

Comment: @christian The header component has a height of 100% and is position fixed at the top of the screen. I did suspect this might be the problem, so I added the HostListener to the main app.component, but I am still not getting any results

Comment: Set the height to something absolute, like 2000px and then try it.

Comment: @christian So in this case, would I need to put the HostListener on the body? 
I have already tried in the app component but it's not working

Answer (score 11):

This is because of the global styles from styles.scss

From styles.scss change height to min-height

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

To this

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This is what worked for me, hope it help!

Answer (score 2):

In your .ts file for the component that you are working on:

```
import {Component, OnInit, HostListener, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common";

...
constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
)
... after ngOnIt {}:
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onWindowScroll() {
    console.log(window.scrollY);
}
```

Make sure that the file is long enough and you should see integers in the console when you scroll down the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If you use scrolling in modals - it's hard to catch the scroll event, but also you can use `window:wheel` event to catch the scroll event for any place even if main page is unscrollable:

```
@HostListener('window:wheel', []) onWindowScroll() {
    console.log('Was scrolled');
}
```