# Impossibile to detect scroll of the page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm facing some problems detecting the scroll of the windows in Angular:

```
    @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
   
    console.log("ciao");
  }
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 @HostListener('window:scroll', \[\]) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148204/angular-8-hostlistenerwindowscroll-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) // for window scroll events
    onScroll(event) {
      ...
    }
```

or for specific div

```
 <div (scroll)="onScroll($event)"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html.  this is the link to working example

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onScroll(): void {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      this.fetchMore()
    }
  }
```